Можно ли запустить два exe файла одновременно?
Есть два exe файла, можно ли создать такой файл, который ты запускаешь, а он запускает два exe одновременно?

не стоит дублировать один и тот же вопрос.

Допустим можно. Возможно они не прямо одновремеено запустятся, какое то к-во микросекунд разница будет. Сморя какой критерий одновремеености. Если срого одновременно то нет.

Конечно. ОС Windows? Запускать хотите через bat? Вносите уточнения в вопрос.

без разницы как, а как сделать с bat?

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask // Постарайтесь сформулировать вопрос так, чтоб он был полезен другим участникам в будущем, а также легко находился в поиске.

Этот вопрос похож на: Запустить .exe файлы c++. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Можно создать батник как вариант и туда вписать программы которые стоит открыть. Для этого открываем блокнот и пишем
@echo off
start ...exe
start....exe
exit
сохраняем с расширением bat (например number.bat) Все можно запускать, откроется мозила и рисовалка, если потребуется добавить еще одну прогу то пишем строку start имя программы.
